# Deleted records are selectable in the same transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-delete

I am using the `mssql-jdbc` JDBC driver to do the following in a single transaction.

Executed the following statement:

```
delete from table1
```

There were around 10 records in the table which were deleted (execute update returned 10). Then, immediately following the delete, executed the following select statement:

```
select count(*) from table1
```

Resultset said that there are still 10 records.

In other DBs like Oracle and Postgres, we get 0, which is what I am expecting.

I do not want autocommit=true behaviour. Also, the two statements need to execute in the same transaction.

Is there anything I can do to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: Marc, thanks for the edits.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b89f517850eb002db4b0fc822672c1a8). Double check your assumptions about what's running how. I have trouble coming up with any arrangement where this could apply, save perhaps for executing the `COUNT(*)` outside the transaction under `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: I am using Spring Transaction. So, I am not manually creating transaction boundaries. Both statements were executed in same method. Transaction Isolation level is ISOLATION_DEFAULT (which is READ_COMMITTED for SQL Server).

Comment: Well as the fiddle shows, it's not the engine producing these results (at least not directly), it's however the engine is being tickled. I suggest you tag your question with the technologies you're using *other* than SQL Server and supply some code so the experts on that can weigh in. If you want to know what your client/driver is doing under the hood, you can use SQL Server Profiler to trace the statements.

Comment: Thanks... I will try that.

Comment: You can also use query in SSMS to run the code in a transaction.  If you want to insure there a transaction, you can add logic for BEGIN TRAN, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK.  After an error (SET XACT_ABORT ON, TRY CATCH, etc.), you can check @@TRANCOPUNT to see if a ROLLBACK is required.

Comment: If you are using an existing transaction that was started with snapshot isolation, it will have access to records deleted after the snapshot was made.  I doubt you are doing this because it sounds like you ran a new query just after.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help... The issue was with a on deletion cascade trigger which had some bugs. As a result, commit was failing. There was no other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for my question.

There was a bug in the on-delete cascade trigger we had added for the table.

As a result, a commit was not happening when records in that table were deleted. Since no JDBC exceptions were being thrown for failures in the trigger, the problem was not apparent from Java end.

There was no other issue.